# How to open your eclipse project in a window?

Tags: java, eclipse, console-application

How do I export my Eclipse project so that it is its own console application sort of thing.

Every time I try to run the .jar file after exporting it, a window pops up saying that it couldn't open the program. Is there some code I need to enter in order to make it its own window, like when you run it in eclipse, except it is its own window and application. Here is an example of how I have coded it:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner text = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Ready:");
        boolean loop2 = true;

        while (loop2 = true) {
            String text1 = text.nextLine();

            switch (text1) {

                case "hi":
                    System.out.println("Greetings!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be nice! I am trying to make this for sending to my friends, too, just so you know.

Comment: [Look at this.](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html) A simple google search would have saved some time :)

Answer (score 0):

In the navigator view, right-click on your project > Export > Java > Jar. Be sure to indicate your class as main class.

Then, once saved, you can run the jar by double clicking on it, or using `java -jar jarfile.jar` from command line.

Comment: You can even do `Export Executable Jar`.

Comment: I don't know if it is the version of Eclipse I'm using, but the only things in Export>General are Ant Buildfiles, Archive Files, File System and Preferences. Also, uner Export>Java there is Jar File, and I tried doing that, but after exporting, Eclipse gives me the message: Jar Export finished with warnings. When I try double clicking the .jar, it another window pops up saying: The Java JAR file "filename.jar" could not be launched. I am using a MAC, if it helps.

Comment: When you're not sure about the version of Eclipse you're using, you should *tell us* which version you're using. Being able to export an Executable Jar is a recent feature.

Comment: Okay. All I know is that I'm using Juno. I'll see if there is an update.

Comment: Do you have a valid JRE configured in your Mac (it is shipped by default, so you should, but I'm asking anyway). To know that, telle us what you get when typing `java -version` in a new terminal. Also, your classname should be `Main` (with a capital M) by conventions

Comment: I did the java -version command in the terminal app and this came out: java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)